# How can I use doctrine query results in the view?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How can I get stand alone elements? For example `$language->LanguageName`.

Here is my controller code:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

protected $entityManager;

public function getEntityManager()
{
    if (null === $this->entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    }
    return $this->entityManager;
}

public function indexAction() {
    $language = $this->getEntityManager()
                     ->getRepository('\LanguagesModule\Entity\LanguageCommon')
                     ->findAll();

    $viewModel = new ViewModel([ 'languages' => $language ]);
    return $viewModel;
}}
```

And here is my view file code...

```
<?php foreach ($this->languages as $language) : ?>
<tr>
    <pre><?php print_r($language) ?></pre>
</tr>
```

as a result I have

```
LanguagesModule\Entity\LanguageCommon Object
(
    [LanguageId:protected] => 1
    [LanguageName:protected] => English
    [LanguageCode2:protected] => en
    [LanguageCode3:protected] => eng
    [LanguageImage:protected] => img_path
    [LanguageActive:protected] => 1
)

LanguagesModule\Entity\LanguageCommon Object
(
    [LanguageId:protected] => 2
    [LanguageName:protected] => Other
    [LanguageCode2:protected] => ot
    [LanguageCode3:protected] => oth
    [LanguageImage:protected] => image_path
    [LanguageActive:protected] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array of entities. So loop over the objects and use the `getters` of your entity to get the value for each field. This should work :

```
<?php foreach ($languages as $language) : ?>
            <tr> 
                <td><?php echo $language->getLanguageId(); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $language->getLanguageName(); ?></td> 
                <td>....</td> 
            </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```